# Не могу могу удалить объект объекта из localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localstorage

Не могу понять в чем проблема, поискал в гугле инфу, самое близкое это было заменить объект. Вроде получилось, но удаляются все элементы из localStorage. Вот код:

```
deleteBook = (id) => {
    const newBooks = {...this.state.books};
    if(newBooks.hasOwnProperty(id)){
        //удаляем объект из Dom
        delete newBooks[id];
        //перезаписываем его в localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("SAVED_BOOK", JSON.stringify(newBooks[id]));
        this.setState({books: newBooks});
    }
};
```

Comment: если вопрос про localStorage - убери код реакт. и подпиши, оставшееся комментариями, что оно делает по твоему мнению.

Comment: @qwabra исправил, реакт код здесь только последняя строчка

Comment: а ещё `const newBooks = {...this.state.books};` элемент которого ты удаляешь тут `delete newBooks[id]`;; кого его `перезаписываем его в localStorage` тыж его удалил

Comment: @qwabra согласен, но заменить его все равно не получается, пробовал просто присвоить пустой объект или строку, он заменяет весь объект локала, а не объект объекта локала

Comment: посмотри ответ. проверь, работает ли, если не работает - напиши мне, потом посмотри на свой код, если не догадаешься в чём у тебя ошибка - напиши мне.

Comment: @qwabra понял, спасибо большое за разъяснение) все получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### как работать с данными в `localStorage` отличными от строк

```
{//пишем
    let obj = { 1: { a: 'A' }, 2: { b: 'b' } };
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj)
    localStorage.setItem("ключ", str);
}

{//читаем
    let str = localStorage.getItem("ключ")
    let obj = JSON.parse(str)
}

{//читаем, правим, пишем
    let str = localStorage.getItem("ключ")
    let obj = JSON.parse(str)
    obj['3'] = { c: '' }
    delete obj['1']
    str = JSON.stringify(obj)
    localStorage.setItem("ключ", str);
}
```